# AngularJS Variable in service is not updating in view?

Tags: angularjs, service

I have spent a couple of days banging my head against the table, reading blog posts, and SO questions around my issue. I tried several variations of the code I have below and none has worked so far. I would appreciate any help.

The taskList variable inside the service does update, but the one in the controller does not.

**Controller**

```
angular.module("TaskManager").controller("mainController", function ($scope, API) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        console.log("Initializing app");
        API.getTasks();

    }


    $scope.tasks = API.taskList;

    $scope.$watch(function(){return API.taskList}, function(newVal, oldVal){

        alert("This is tasklist in controller" + newVal);
    }, true)


});
```

**Service**

```
angular.module("TaskManager").service("API", function ($http, $rootScope) {

    const apiKey = "PUH";
    var taskList = [1,2,3,4];
    const getTasks = function () {
        $http.get("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/jquerytaskmanager/collections/tasks?apiKey=" + apiKey).then(function (data) {
           taskList = data; 
           console.log(taskList);
        });
    };

    $rootScope.$watch(function(){return taskList}, function(newVal, oldVal){

        alert(taskList);
        taskList = newVal;


        console.log(taskList);

    }, true)

    return {
        getTasks,
        taskList

    }
});
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">

        <ul id="mainMenu" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-4"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu</a></li>
            <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Task</a></li>
            <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-4"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Manage Categories</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="mainContainer container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col 6">
            <h2>Tasks</h2>



        </div>

    </div>



            <ul>
                <li class="taskContainer" ng-repeat="task in tasks" >

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s6">
                             <span class="taskName"> {{task.task_name}}</span> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col s6">
                            <button class="btn blue darken-4 waves-effect waves-light  ">Edit</button> <button class="btn red darken-4 waves-effect waves-light ">Delete</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </li>

            </ul>








</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the $http promise from the service:

```
app.service("API", function($http) {
    this.getTasks = function() {
        return $http.get(url);
    };
});
```

Then in the controller, extract the data from the promise:

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, API) {
    this.$onInit = function () {
        console.log("Initializing app");
        API.getTasks().then(function(response) {
            $scope.tasks = response.data;
        });    
    };
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Tha took care of it, do you know why my implementation did not work?

Comment: I recommend passing promises as the best approach for working with asynchronous APIs. Dirty checking with watchers is inefficient. Passing references which are later filled in with data relies on dirty checking to work. Don't depend on watchers; just use promises.